# Turn Push Notifications On and Off from within App with Parse

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have been advised that I should allow users to turn push notifications on and off from within my app. I am using Parse to manage my push notifications. I have everything setup so that a user can register for notifications by pressing "Allow." when the push alert pops up. My question though, is about how I would permit the user to turn push notifications ON from within the app if they had originally said "Don't Allow." I know that the push notification alert will only display once. Does anyone have any ideas? Thanks!

**My App Delegate:**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:
(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    [Parse setApplicationId:@"APP_ID"
    clientKey:@"CLIENT_KEY"];
    [PFAnalytics trackAppOpenedWithLaunchOptions:launchOptions];
    //other code
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application
didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {

    // Store the deviceToken in the current installation and save it to Parse.
    PFInstallation *currentInstallation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];
    [currentInstallation setDeviceTokenFromData:deviceToken];
    [currentInstallation saveInBackground];
}
```

**User Settings View Controller:**

```
-(IBAction) switchValueChanged {

    if (toggleSwitch.on) {

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication]
        registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
        (UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert |
        UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge |
        UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)];    

        PFInstallation *currentInstallation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];
        [currentInstallation setDeviceTokenFromData:deviceToken];
        [currentInstallation saveInBackground];
    }
    else {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do that. The user has to manually go into the Notification Settings and set your app for notifications. Apparently the reason being is that Apple does not want an app pestering a user to allow if the user has already said no once.

I suggest having your app display an alert to advise the user of turning notifications on.